# To what degree can "the inadequacy of a binary universe" be seen as a theme in the Quantum Thief trilogy? (Spoiler Warning)

Tags: quantum-thief

Particularly as relates to the binary choices of the classic Prisoner's Dilemma and the ultimate strategy adopted by the All Defector in the Causal Angel.

Mieli creates a new universe that works differently than the old, and although details are not provided, I get the sense that this dilemma is a driving force in her choices creating the new universe.

Part of the reason this occurred to me is due to the non-binary nature of quantum computing.